# Visual Studio for Mac is not letting me create a new forms project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I am having a weird problem. I cannot create a Xamarin.Forms application on mac. When I click it and enter a company name and app name, it just doesn't let me click next. What gives? I've tried clicking and checking every button on the page nothing seems to do it. I can create a console application but the "next" button is never active for any multiplatform app. Help!

using Mac OS High Serria 10.13.6,
Mono is installed

Using

[image]

Comment: I can create a forms app on VS/Mac 8.4.7 on MacOS 10.15.4. What version of VS/Mac are you using? What version of Mono?

Comment: try reinstalling VS Mac

Comment: Im using Mono 6.6.0

Comment: @WilliamEhrenberg Hi , when installing VS for Mac , could you see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmniO.png) to select iOS and Android options .

Comment: Yes, I didn't click them because I just want to publish to Mac and pc. Is there an option to do just that?

Comment: @WilliamEhrenberg You can download VS for mac installer to configure that ,then restart VS . It will work .

Answer (score 0):

You can download **[Visual Studio for Mac installer](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/mac/)** to configure development environment .

The list of available workloads is displayed. Select the components you wish to use:

[image]

Also can have a look at this official [doc here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/installation?view=vsmac-2019).

=============================Update===================================

If need to create a Mac console App ：

Click on the **New Project**... button to open the New Project dialog box, then select **Mac** > **App** > **Cocoa App** and click the Next button:

[image]

**Note** :

There is no direct way in Visual Studio to create a multi-platfrom Console App .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just wanted to make an app for Mac and Windows. I am using a console application and gtk#

Comment: Hi， I have updated answer . Maybe you misunderstand the cross-platform app in Xamarin. I you want to make an app for Mac and Windows , you need to create each console app for each platform . There is no direct way in Visual Studio can create a multi-platform console app . There is a cross-platform app in Visual Studio is Xamrin for mobile platform , such as **Android/iOS/UWP** .